# Can't load flat binary file into kernel

Tags: operating-system, osdev

NOTE - I don't have paging set up yet and my kernel is multi-boot, ELF. I do have irqs and the isrs done.

So I have this GAS file here:

```
.section .text
.global _start

_start:
    mov $0xDEADBEEF, %eax
```

And GRUB2 setup to load the flat binary file:

```
menuentry "fOS-Terminal (25x80)" {
    multiboot /boot/fos.elf
    module /modules/program.bin
    set gfxmode=80x25
}
```

And here in my kernel.c, I can parse the multiboot header to get the module's address and I am calling it:

```
typedef void (*call_module_t)(void);
call_module_t start_program = (call_module_t)mbd->mods_addr;
start_program();
```

Right now I am trying to compile my GAS file into a flat binary with these commands:

```
i686-elf-as --32 ./iso/modules/program.s -o ./iso/modules/program.o

i686-elf-ld -fPIC -shared --oformat binary ./iso/modules/program.o -o ./iso/modules/program.bin
```

PROBLEM - GRUB2 is surely loading the kernel, multi-boot header is telling me it's at address  - 0x100ac but when I go there, I get the exception: INVALID OPCODE.

This seems helpful but is not :(

https://littleosbook.github.io/book.pdf#page=49&zoom=auto,-100,472

EDIT - 1 So when I gdb'd to the calling function, this comes up:
[image: The pointer seems to point nowhere]

Comment: You should try stepping through with a debugger. _GDB_ would be useful. You could see what happens when the jump occurs. One observation is that `_start: mov $0xDEADBEEF, %eax` may wander through memory after the mov. What happens if you go into an infinite loop after with something like `jmp .`?

Comment: If you created a minimal complete verifiable example it would help. Something complete that we can build and test.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Please have a look at the edit, BTW I just realized the pointer isn't pointing to any _start label there. This seems trouble.

Comment: All I can say is that 0x100ac doesn't appear to be a address to the start of your program. I would expect a module would be loaded into a separate page than the bootloader (I have never tried multiboot modules this way, so I could be wrong). Without a [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) i can't say why

Comment: @MichaelPetch I am really new OSDev, could you suggest a resource to mult-boot modules?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem

```
typedef void (*call_module_t)(void);
call_module_t start_program = (call_module_t)mbd->mods_addr;
start_program();
```

`mbd->mods_addr` is the address of modules structure table. And not the address to module itself.
so what is the solution?

```
unsigned int* modules = (unsigned int*)mbd->mods_addr;
if (mbd->mods_count > 0)
{
    unsigned int addr = modules[0];
    unsigned int size = modules[1];
    call_module_t start_program = (call_module_t)addr;
    start_program();
}
else
    painc("module wasn't loaded");
```